# Ruby and Mysql2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

I'm trying to install a 5 years old website locally that is a 1.9.2 Ruby website. For it, I need mysql2 gem file, but I constantly fail with the error mesasge belove.

```
Installing mysql2 0.3.20 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/li/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p330/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160114-7831-msi06n.rb extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... no
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
-----
Using mysql_config at /usr/bin/mysql_config
-----
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
-----
Setting libpath to /usr/lib64/mysql
-----
creating Makefile

make  clean

make
gcc -I. -I/home/li/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p330/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/home/li/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p330/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/li/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p330/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/usr/include/mysql -DHAVE_RUBY_THREAD_H -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_RB_HASH_DUP -DHAVE_RB_INTERN3 -DHAVE_MYSQL_H -DHAVE_ERRMSG_H -DHAVE_MYSQLD_ERROR_H    -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long  -fPIC -Wall -funroll-loops  -o mysql2_ext.o -c mysql2_ext.c
In file included from ./mysql2_ext.h:32:0,
                 from mysql2_ext.c:1:
/usr/include/ruby/thread.h:26:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘void’
 void *rb_thread_call_with_gvl(void *(*func)(void *), void *data1);
 ^
In file included from ./mysql2_ext.h:41:0,
                 from mysql2_ext.c:1:
./client.h:39:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘typedef’
 typedef struct {
 ^
Makefile:180: recipe for target 'mysql2_ext.o' failed
make: *** [mysql2_ext.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/li/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p330@trafo/gems/mysql2-0.3.20 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/li/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p330@trafo/extensions/x86_64-linux/1.9.1/mysql2-0.3.20/gem_make.out
```

Can you please help me out a bit?

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/572) will help.

Comment: Looking into it, sorry for slow responding, a lot of stuff came in recently and have to make a priority list. You know how this goes...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! Regarding to that links solution, I've removed ruby and found that there were multiple versions installed. After the remove, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue but could not remove the system ruby as it was used outside of RVM.

However, it turns out that all you need to remove for this to work is the `ruby-devel` package. It seems like for some reason, when attempting to compile the mysql native extensions inside RVM, some of the included files are taken from the system include directory instead of the RVM include directory, leading to a conflict between the ruby versions.